# SQLite3- how can I speed up this SELECT query?

Tags: sql, select, sqlite, query-optimization

```
SELECT DISTINCT sid,
    usrname,
    errcode,
    msg,
    DATE,
    TIME
FROM ecode e,
    action a
WHERE e.errcode = a.STATUS LIMIT 250;
```

I am developing a tool to look through server logs, but this query is painfully slow, and I'm not sure why (I am fairly new to SQL, so it's probably something basic). I am running this query against a database of server logs. errcode and msg come from the ecode table, all other properties come from the action table (which has ~100k entries). The ecode table contains a list of certain status codes that we consider errors. This query takes around 8 seconds to execute regardless of how many results I limit it to (be it 25 or the entire table), so I suspect that that is the culprit. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at your index usage. See [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/).

Comment: Why are you using DISTINCT? Are you aware that LIMIT does not make much sense without ORDER BY?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yep, indexes massively improved the speed.

Comment: @CL. I didn't originally write this query (the original query was wrapped in another SELECT query that would order the results. You were right about DISTINCT, it is utterly pointless due to how the server keeps logs), but I was able to massively improve the efficiency by indexing a couple columns and using a WHERE clause to pull the errors from the same day that the query is being run, as opposed to LIMIT. Took the query from ~8 seconds to ~1 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you have proper index  on

```
 table ecode column  errcode 
 table action column status
```

and ( a suggestion ) you  should use explicit join sintax

```
  SELECT DISTINCT sid, usrname, errcode, msg, date, time 
  FROM ecode e
  INNER JOIN  action a ON   e.errcode = a.status 
  LIMIT 250
```

Comment: Yep, this was it. Using indexes and a join (as well as rewriting it to not use LIMIT) took the query from ~8 seconds to ~1 second. Thanks!